# R hist() error message: Invalid number of breaks

Tags: r, csv, histogram

I've been trying to look at the distribution of my data to see if it is normal and using the hist() function in r. It worked initially and I saw that the data was very left-skewed so I tried to log transform it and I was getting the error message "invalid number of breaks". I am using r studio Version 1.0.136 on Mac and here is an example of my dataset in Microsoft excel as a csv file:

[image: screenshot of csv dataset]

My r code:

```
#Import my dataset
library(readr)
LeafWaterPotentials <- read_csv("~/Desktop/LeafWaterPotentials.csv", col_types = cols(Block = col_factor(levels = c("1", "2", "3")), Solute.Potential = col_number(), Treatment = col_factor(levels = c("nID", "ID", "nInD", "InD")), Vapro.Reading = col_number(), WP = col_number(), leaf.turgor.potential = col_number(), water.potential.Mpa = col_number()))

#check whether the data has normal distribution
hist(LeafWaterPotentials$Solute.Potential) #distribution is skewed

#try log-transforming data (also tried sqrt and get same error)
hist(log(LeafWaterPotentials$Solute.Potential))
```

OUTPUT:

> Error in hist.default(log(LeafWaterPotentials$Solute.Potential)) :
>     invalid number of 'breaks'

```
#Check summary of dataset
summary(LeafWaterPotentials)
```

OUTPUT:

```
summary(LeafWaterPotentials)

      Cage         Plant       Treatment         Block        WP        water.potential.Mpa
 Min.   :1.0   Min.   :1.00   Length:144         1:48   Min.   : 4.61   Min.   :-4.120     
 1st Qu.:2.0   1st Qu.:2.75   Class :character   2:48   1st Qu.: 8.43   1st Qu.:-1.115     
 Median :3.5   Median :4.50   Mode  :character   3:48   Median : 9.83   Median :-0.983     
 Mean   :3.5   Mean   :4.50                             Mean   :11.22   Mean   :-1.122     
 3rd Qu.:5.0   3rd Qu.:6.25                             3rd Qu.:11.14   3rd Qu.:-0.843     
 Max.   :6.0   Max.   :8.00                             Max.   :41.20   Max.   :-0.461     
                                                        NA's   :1       NA's   :1          
 Vapro.Reading    Solute.Potential leaf.turgor.potential
 Min.   : 243.0   Min.   :-4.006   Min.   :-1.72500     
 1st Qu.: 307.0   1st Qu.:-1.026   1st Qu.:-0.21300     
 Median : 348.0   Median :-0.877   Median :-0.08400     
 Mean   : 398.4   Mean   :-1.004   Mean   :-0.05753     
 3rd Qu.: 407.0   3rd Qu.:-0.774   3rd Qu.: 0.06800     
 Max.   :1589.0   Max.   :-0.613   Max.   : 2.43700     
 NA's   :7        NA's   :7        NA's   :7
```

Here is a screenshot as the coded output looks a bit muddled:
[image: data summary() output]

I am relatively new to r but I was wondering if the error had something to do with the NA values but then I've created histograms of log-transformed data with NAs before and had no issue.

Comment: `LeafWaterPotentials$Solute.Potential` all seem to be negative, so `log` will produce `NaN`, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, yes it is clear to me now that it was a problem with the log-transformation of data rather than the hist() code and so I shall make the values positive before analysing them.